# Git - Chaining cmds (i.e. ls-files) to submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-ls-files

Is there a way to chain cmds to submodules within your repo? *I am looking for built-in methods as I need this to be portable and without secondary installations.*

In my case, I have a workflow pipeline that is based on ls-files (and log) and need to be able to see files that match certain conditions, even if they are in submodules.

i.e.

```
git ls-files some/file/path/above/my/submodules/globed-file
```

Only shows files within the current repo and ignores the submodule's files.

Comment: Note: Git 2.11 will soon add `git ls-files --recurse-submodules`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @VonC Thank you for the update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

June 2015: You can try to execute your command in each submodules, using [`git submodule foreach`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

```
git submodule --quiet --recursive foreach "git ls-files yourFile"
```

One of the submodule will return something, if that file is present in it.

Note that with Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016), you can use instead:

```
git ls-files --recurse-submodules
```

See "[finding a list of files (e.g. using `git ls-files`) including submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40311391/6309)".

Comment: Thanks, I've used foreach on the submodule option, it of course does not include the process on the git repo files containing those submodules. This is the only answer I could could come up with also, I'll just have to run multiple cmds and place the union of those results on the bash pipeline.