# GIT: finding a list of files (e.g. using git ls-files) including submodules

Tags: git, github

I've been trying to figure out how to get a list of all files in a git repo including those contained within submodules. Currently, `git ls-files` will provide the top level submodule directory but not the files contained within the submodule. On further investigation, I found that using `git submodule`, you can recursively find all of the submodules and then go a `git ls-files` using:

```
git submodule --quiet foreach --recursive "git ls-files"
```

The only problem with this is that the results are the path from the submodule but I need the full path from the repo. So for the following

e.g. /some/path/to/gitrepo/source/submodule/[file1, file2]

What I see is:

```
file1
file2
```

What I would like to see is:

```
source/submodule/file1
source/submodule/file2
```

Is there a way to do this? From the documentation, there are some pre-defined variables ($name, $path, $sha1 and $toplevel) but I'm not sure how to use these to get the desired results.

Comment: Note: you will have `git ls-files --recurse-submodules` with Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40311391/6309). It can be run from the main parent repo and will produce the full path.

Answer (score 14):

Another approach is possible with Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016)

```
git ls-files --recurse-submodules
```

See [commit 75a6315](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75a6315f7416a2fd559d0b0c7352b4f1cd10e186), [commit 07c01b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07c01b9fd927b35375bd3a7d4d9dbf7bb8509f09), [commit e77aa33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e77aa336f116e8ff8a72d034494b3a476b78c3ee), [commit 74866d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74866d75793559e8b351a17100679f83b96972ca) (07 Oct 2016) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1c2b1f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c2b1f7018ba7d5f6a5d949e29e4eaeeef3261e2), 26 Oct 2016)</sup>

> ### `ls-files`: optionally recurse into submodules

> "`git ls-files`" learned "`--recurse-submodules`" option that can be used to get a listing of tracked files across submodules (i.e. this only works with "`--cached`" option, not for listing untracked or ignored files).
>
> This would be a useful tool to sit on the upstream side of a pipe that is read with xargs to work on all working tree files from the top-level superproject.

As shown [in this test](https://github.com/git/git/blob/75a6315f7416a2fd559d0b0c7352b4f1cd10e186/t/t3007-ls-files-recurse-submodules.sh#L104-L119), the output would include the full path of the file, starting from the main parent repo.

The [`git ls-files` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1c2b1f7018ba7d5f6a5d949e29e4eaeeef3261e2/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L141-L143) now includes:

```
--recurse-submodules
```

> Recursively calls ls-files on each submodule in the repository.
> Currently there is only support for the --cached mode.

---

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) adds to the `ls-files --recurse-submodules` robustness:

See [commit 2cfe66a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cfe66a8ee57fb3da18c262db8e6df95e263510b), [commit 2e5d650](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e5d6503bdc92260eae9c58b9fd1add7014bb853) (13 Apr 2017) by [Jacob Keller (`jacob-keller`)](https://github.com/jacob-keller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2d646e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d646e3e1fd0ae7f525034abee73d06ac8946729), 24 Apr 2017)</sup>

> ### `ls-files`: fix `recurse-submodules` with nested submodules

> Since commit [e77aa33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e77aa336f116e8ff8a72d034494b3a476b78c3ee) ("ls-files: optionally recurse into
> submodules", 2016-10-07, git 2.11) `ls-files` has known how to recurse into
> submodules when displaying files.
>
> Unfortunately this fails for certain cases, including when nesting more
> than one submodule, called from within a submodule that itself has
> submodules, or when the `GIT_DIR` environemnt variable is set.
>
> Prior to commit [b58a68c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b58a68c1c1874ff155699d82947c9f026f431cb3) ("`setup`: allow for prefix to be passed to
> git commands", 2017-03-17, git 2.13-rc0) this resulted in an error indicating that
> `--prefix` and `--super-prefix` were incompatible.
>
> After this commit, instead, the process loops forever with a `GIT_DIR` set
> to the parent and continuously reads the parent submodule files and recursing forever.
>
> Fix this by preparing the environment properly for submodules when setting up the child process. This is similar to how other commands such as grep behave.

---

As noted with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the config `submodule.recurse` would not work.

See [commit 7d15fdb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d15fdbe4c468c953eef170de645538fd7ccb4b8) (04 Oct 2020) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9d19e17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d19e1773cd705b79dcaca25add9aaa7e9debeff), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`gitsubmodules doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d15fdbe4c468c953eef170de645538fd7ccb4b8): invoke 'ls-files' with '--recurse-submodules'
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> [`git ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d15fdbe4c468c953eef170de645538fd7ccb4b8/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files))</sup> was never taught to respect the `submodule.recurse` configuration variable, and [it is too late now to change that](https://lore.kernel.org/git/pull.732.git.1599707259907.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/#u), but still the command is mentioned in 'gitsubmodules(7)' as if it does respect that config.
>
> Adjust the call in 'gitsubmodules(7)' by calling '`ls-files`' with the '`--recurse-submodules`' option.

`gitsubmodules` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d15fdbe4c468c953eef170de645538fd7ccb4b8/Documentation/gitsubmodules.txt#L256-L259):

> `git ls-files --recurse-submodules`
>
> [NOTE]
> `git ls-files` also requires its own `--recurse-submodules` flag.

---

[With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71428178/6309), `git ls-files --stage --recurse-submodule` is also supported.

---

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), stop using git `--super-prefix` and narrow the scope of its use to the submodule--helper.

See [commit 4002ec3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4002ec3dcf0f89db46fbdf56549218c573a9c0f2), [commit f5a6be9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5a6be9d547700b7bd3018f1c0daf3d257cb2762), [commit 04f1fab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04f1fab4a13ad9eb2757809765720508abeb38da), [commit 99a32d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99a32d87f82683a3d3ff4a35dd551060c113a82c), [commit 677c981](https://github.com/git/git/commit/677c981260854f0acc1b7cd4cce85d46f1b76f06), [commit bb61a96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb61a962d2e759754fca35e4b31f73122eed49fc), [commit f0a5e5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0a5e5ad57ae729d9971bdb6bdaa82c1d85bd062), [commit 49eb1d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49eb1d388ae618b61058d14b811684a89bdf84b6) (20 Dec 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit 0d1806e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d1806e53de6ac26021d8aab918d76381287f339) (20 Dec 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d4c5400](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4c540086510c36a6f61e7764cbed1dc474b4a8e), 05 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`read-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4002ec3dcf0f89db46fbdf56549218c573a9c0f2): add "--super-prefix" option, eliminate global
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> The "`--super-prefix`" option to "`git`" was initially added in [commit 74866d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74866d75793559e8b351a17100679f83b96972ca) ("`git`: make super-prefix option", 2016-10-07, Git v2.11.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c2b1f7018ba7d5f6a5d949e29e4eaeeef3261e2) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cc2e70264e0fcba04f9ef791d144bbc8b501206)) for:
>
> - use with "`ls-files`" ([commit e77aa33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e77aa336f116e8ff8a72d034494b3a476b78c3ee) ("`ls-files`: optionally recurse into submodules", 2016-10-07, Git v2.11.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c2b1f7018ba7d5f6a5d949e29e4eaeeef3261e2) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cc2e70264e0fcba04f9ef791d144bbc8b501206))), and shortly thereafter
> - "`submodule--helper`" ([commit 89c8626](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89c8626557621ef000930da3c8a23fa03ad7e01a) ("submodule helper: support super prefix", 2016-12-08, Git v2.12.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da2b74eeec0b12d7b20d34a5e284295f81ad40a8) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7dffce1cebde29a0c4b309a79e4345450bf352a))) and
> - "`grep`" ([0281e48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0281e487fd913bd9a32a710f3109ff3002f3e4a9) ("`grep`: optionally recurse into submodules", 2016-12-16, Git v2.12.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55d128ae06b7b82f867961b677984620612a201c) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/787f75f0567aa8c7347544c65e9d3bc6640a27d4))).
>
> It wasn't until [commit 3d41542](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d415425c7b6ca0d2243a4589672369e7a02fc2c) ("`unpack-trees`: support super-prefix option", 2017-01-17, Git v2.12.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2243d229f75be41318db8798fc90399dd6dedb42)) that "`read-tree`" made use of it.
>
> At the time it made sense, but since then we've made "`ls-files`" recurse in-process in [commit 188dce1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/188dce131fa95d85ddc024a1bc7d2b7fc5da4424) ("`ls-files`: use repository object", 2017-06-22, Git v2.14.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85ce4a6828a418a22c69a870b3e059481b4263d6) listed in [batch #14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50ff9ea4a0770c8b1bfe3f98f09728427c0c6cc7)), "`grep`" in [commit f9ee2fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9ee2fcdfa05586b6a4476c7aa5f4f0162e48455) ("`grep`: recurse in-process using 'struct repository'", 2017-08-02, Git v2.15.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5aa0b6c506c1f1336d0e713bf8225509e9ebb9f5) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0294f474e16840f4efb3f4da3329ba46f53efa7)), and finally "`submodule--helper`" in the preceding commits.
>
> Let's also remove it from "`read-tree`", which allows us to remove the option to "`git`" itself.
>
> We can do this because the only remaining user of it is the submodule API, which will now invoke "`read-tree`" with its new "`--super-prefix`" option.
> It will only do so when the "`submodule_move_head()`" function is called.
>
> That "`submodule_move_head()`" function was then only invoked by "`read-tree`" itself, but now rather than setting an environment variable to pass "`--super-prefix`" between `cmd_read_tree()` we: - Set a new `"super_prefix"` in "struct `unpack_trees_options"`.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4002ec3dcf0f89db46fbdf56549218c573a9c0f2/Documentation/git.txt#L16):

> [--config-env==]  []

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `git submodule` documentation, which says:

> `foreach`
>
> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.
>   The command has access to the variables `$name`, `$path`, `$sha1` and
>   `$toplevel`: `$name` is the name of the relevant submodule section in
>   .gitmodules, `$path` is the name of the submodule directory relative
>   to the superproject, `$sha1` is the commit as recorded in the
>   superproject, and `$toplevel` is the absolute path to the top-level
>   of the superproject.

Given the above information, you can do something like:

```
git submodule foreach 'git ls-files | sed "s|^|$path/|"'
```

In this example, we're simply taking the output from `git ls-files` in a submodule and using `sed` to prepend the value of `$path`, which is the path of the submodule relative to the parent project's toplevel directory.

Comment: This is technically wrong if $path contains '|' (or whatever other character you use for separating sed). You can make it extra robust like this: `git submodule --quiet foreach 'export path;bash -c '\''git ls-files | sed "s/^/${path/\//\\/}\//"'\'`

Comment: Despite the problematic sed trick I like this answer. pointing me to 'git submodule foreach'. I did [ git submodule foreach 'git ls-files --others --exclude-standard' ] to list files that are ready to be added.