# Find all submodules in git and their commits

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project on my git repositary which contains submodules and those submodules contains feather submodules.

Since I am not responsible to all the submodules, I don't know what changed there after I updated the commit I was looking at. For this reason I would like to document the current state.

This means, I would like to know all the submodules I am using (explicit and non-explicit). For each submodules I would like to know its Tag and\or commit.

I found:

```
git ls-files --stage
```

helpful, but shows only commits from my repository and not inside the submodules.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git submodule foreach --recursive "git describe --tags HEAD --exact-match 2>/dev/null || git rev-parse HEAD"
```

Recursively in each submodule, run the commands `git describe --tags HEAD --exact-match 2>/dev/null || git rev-parse HEAD`

First try to find the most recent tag that exactly points at the head commit of each submodule. If no tag is found, then return the commit.

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-files --stage
```

> helpful, but shows only commits from my repository and not inside the submodules.

Before Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), many output modes of "ls-files" do not work with its "--recurse-submodules" option, but the "--stage" mode has now been taught to work with it.

See [commit 290eada](https://github.com/git/git/commit/290eada0ac9d374501fa24268c2e1ec8b8924358) (23 Feb 2022) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7a4e06c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a4e06c42a1e06f43f90b302cad09f31ec438ff1), 06 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/290eada0ac9d374501fa24268c2e1ec8b8924358): support `--recurse-submodules --stage`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> [e77aa33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e77aa336f116e8ff8a72d034494b3a476b78c3ee) ("`ls-files`: optionally recurse into submodules", 2016-10-10, Git v2.11.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c2b1f7018ba7d5f6a5d949e29e4eaeeef3261e2) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cc2e70264e0fcba04f9ef791d144bbc8b501206)) taught `ls-files` the `--recurse-submodules` argument, but only in a limited set of circumstances.
>
> In particular, `--stage` was unsupported, perhaps because there was no `repo_find_unique_abbrev()`, which was only introduced in [8bb9557](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8bb95572b05d70cce6ea6eef9396cdaf6b34b14f) ("`sha1`-name.c``: add `repo_find_unique_abbrev_r()`", 2019-04-16, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b179f3175d1a152b1d22ce8352efda34b258ce2) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a6c0f10a70a6eb101c213b09ae82a9cad252743)).
>
> This function is needed for using `--recurse-submodules` with --stage.

`git ls-files` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/290eada0ac9d374501fa24268c2e1ec8b8924358/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L159):

> ### `--recurse-submodules`:
>
> Recursively calls `ls-files` on each active submodule in the repository.
>
> Currently there is only support for the `--cached` and `--stage` modes.